# How to modify pretrained Resnet model

Tags: neural-network, resnet, transfer-learning

I am working on a project in which I want to break a pre trained resnet50 model into 2 parts.
Part1 : (conv1 layer to layer4 of resnet50)
Part2 : ( layer 5 of the resnet50)

And then there's my modification as
My modification : (ROI pooling , 7X7)

Then I want to make new model as
part1 -> my modification -> part2
Note : arrow indicates data flow

important thing to note is that for input image of 1x3x224x224
output of part1 will have size of 1x1024x14x14.
Now for N bounding boxes ROIPooling of output size(14x14) will produce outputs
of size Nx1024x14x14 which do not change the size of feature maps instead it makes a batch of N such 1024x14x14 feature maps. As the size has not been changed, they can be directly used by the part2

I want to know , how do I do it using pytorch ?
I want to give a single image per batch, for that 1 image we have multiple bounding boxes … And I want prediction for each bounding box.

How do I write this using pytorch ?

Answer (score 0):

@Bhavesh, I think this is what you need. The code uses pre-trained resnet-34 with bounding boxes. [bounding-box-prediction-from-scratch-using-pytorch-a8525da51ddc](https://towardsdatascience.com/bounding-box-prediction-from-scratch-using-pytorch-a8525da51ddc)